# Non UIViewController Class in Swift

Tags: ios, class, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS. I want to know how to create a non UIViewController based class. I mean to say the class not extending from UIViewcontroller.

I want so because I want to call some Async HTTP url and parse the Json/XML in non UI class. I just want to do them in a separate class from UIViewcontroller classes.

Comment: You can select a different Parent Class(such as NSObject) from the drop down list of file creation window, while creating your new file.

Comment: And you can change it in the header as well: `@interface YourClass : NSObject` (for instance)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I got some points. please can you give me a sample code. pseudo code

Comment: Unlike objective-c Swift classes don't need superclasses. So if you want to create s class that is unrelated to UIKit it doesn't need to be a subclass of anything

Comment: At least try the BARE MINIMAL amount of research before posting a question, a search instantly finds this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class without inheritance like this:

```
class JSONObject{
    var url: NSURL?

    internal func parseJSON() -> NSArray {
        // Code to parse your json
        return []
    }
}
```

and then you can create an instance of the class elsewhere using something like this:

```
var newJSONObject: JSONObject = JSONObject()
newJSONObject.url = NSURL(string: "www.somejson.php")
newJSONObject.parseJSON()
```